# Volume of Shapes

Tags: volume, geometry

I'm doing some maths revision at home from a GSCE book and I'm a bit stuck. I'm not sure how to start off. (I know the formulae for a volume of cone and a formulae for a volume of a sphere but I don't know how that will help me).

QUESTION:

> If a cone with perpendicular height $6h$ and radius $2h$ has the same volume as a sphere of radius $r$, show that $r = \sqrt[3]{6h}$.

Comment: Type \$\sqrt{x+y}\$ to get $\sqrt{x+y}$ or \$\root {m+n} \of {x+y}\$to get $\root {m+n} \of {x+y}$.

Comment: Appending to @GitGud:  another approach is `$\sqrt[m+n]{x+y}$` for $\sqrt[m+n]{x+y}$

Comment: @anorton Yours is easier to type. Thanks.

Comment: Note that your equation is dimensionally inconsistent (in a physical sense). It should be $r=\sqrt[3]{6h^3}$.

Answer (score 2):

The volume of a cone is $\frac{1}{3}\pi (\rm{radius})^2(\rm{height})$, which in this case is $\frac{1}{3}\pi (2h)^2(6h) = 8\pi h^3$.

The volume of a sphere is $\frac{4}{3}\pi (\rm{radius})^3$, which in this case is $\frac{4}{3}\pi r^3$.

You're told that these volumes are equal: $8\pi h^3 = \frac{4}{3} \pi r^3$. Can you see what to do from here?

Answer (score 0):

From the formulas for the area of a circle and cone:
$$V_{\text{circ}} = \frac{4}{3}\pi r^3$$
$$V_{\text{cone}} = \frac{1}{3}\pi \underbrace{(2h)^2}_{\text{cone radius}}\cdot\underbrace{(6h)}_{\text{cone height}}$$

We are told that *the volumes are the same*.  Thus, we can set:
$$V_{\text{circ}} =V_{\text{cone}}$$
Thus:
$$\frac{4}{3}\pi r^3  = \frac{1}{3}\pi(2h)^2\cdot(6h)$$

Simplifying the $(2h)^2$:
$$\frac{4}{3}\pi r^3  = \frac{1}{3}\pi(4r^2)(6h)$$
Now, multiply by $\frac{3}{4}$:
$$\pi r^3  = \pi(r^2)(6h)$$

Can you work from here?  If you need more help, just leave a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Volume of cone $$V_1=\dfrac 13 \pi R^2 H$$
R=2h,H=6h
$$V_1=\dfrac 13 \pi {(2h)}^2 6h$$

Volume of sphere $$V_2=\dfrac 43 \pi r^3$$
but $$V_1=V_2$$
$$\dfrac 13 \pi {(2h)}^2 6h=\dfrac 43 \pi r^3$$
$$8\pi h^3=\dfrac 43 \pi r^3$$
$$r^3=\dfrac{24h^3\pi}{4\pi}$$
$$r^3=6h^3$$
$$r=\sqrt[3]{6}h$$

Comment: due to slower connection I couldn't see that there are already answer